# CyclicReferencesAware attribute - StackOverflow exception

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, poco

I've been trying to implement POCO over WCF (using Entity Framework 4.0) - just like this - http://devblog.petrellyn.com/?p=278

I have many cases of

Object A
 - refs list of Object B

For each Object B
 - refs Object A

I've debugged this and the reference goes on forever, i.e.

User "joe" has a collection of Teams.
  Team[0] has a reference to User "joe".
    User "joe" has a collection of Teams.
      Team[0] has a reference to User "joe".

And so on.  Nothing special here I would think.  Although I'm wondering if this is where my problem is?

However after adding the much blogged CyclicReferencesAware attribute I get a new Stack Overflow exception.  So this still looks like it's not really sorted out the cyclic dependencies.

Running out of ideas now - anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I could have wasted a full day over nothing!

The cyclic attribute does indeed work, BUT NOT WITH THE WCF TEST CLIENT!

[WcfTestClient.exe not able to handle circular reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686960/wcftestclient-exe-not-able-to-handle-circular-reference)

Will leave answer here as sure to help someone else in future.